# UWP - Bind TextBox.Text to Nullable<int>

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp

Is it correct that it is not currently possible to bind to any `Nullable<T>` in Universal XAML Apps?

I found this link from 2013:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/befb9603-b8d6-468d-ad36-ef82a9e29749/textbox-text-binding-on-nullable-types?forum=winappswithcsharp

Stating that:

*Binding to nullable values isn't supported in Windows 8 Store apps.  It just didn't make it into this release.  We've already got bugs on this behavior for v.Next.*

But can it really be that this has not been fixed yet?

My Binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Serves, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Serves"/>
```

My Property:

```
public int? Serves
{
    get { return _serves; ; }
    set
    {
        _serves = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And the error I get in my output:

```
Error: Cannot save value from target back to source. 
BindingExpression: 
    Path='Serves' 
    DataItem='MyAssembly.MyNamespace.RecipeViewModel, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String').
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like it's not fixed. As XAML is using a build-in converter, in this case you can probably exchange it with your own, dealing with nullables:

XAML:

```xml
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:NullConverter x:Key="NullableIntConverter"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Serves, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource NullableIntConverter}}" Header="Serves"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```cs
public class NullConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    { return value; }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        int temp;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value) || !int.TryParse((string)value, out temp)) return null;
        else return temp;
    }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int? _serves;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaiseProperty(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    public int? Serves
    {
        get { return _serves; }
        set { _serves = value; RaiseProperty("Serves"); }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is also my workaround. I'm just a bit amazed this isn't implemented yet.

Comment: @TroelsLarsen I guess they are just overloaded with more important bugs, as this one can be easily bypassed. [Similar bug](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24720929/2681948), which can be easily 'repaired' with converter.

Comment: @Rommasz: True. With the similarities of WPF and UWP, omissions like this just stand out more. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: Still not fixed as of 2019. Crazy thing is I had no problems at first. Then I changed the target version of my project to the latest version of Win10 (originally it was targeting an older version but not *that* old), and suddenly every Nullable int binding was throwing a "no implicit converison between object and nullable int" error...

Comment: Hi @Romasz , I implemented your solution but I got the same error. To solve it I have changed method Convert like this

`public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return value;
            return value.ToString();
        }`